# Data not getting added to LocalDB using Entity Framework in Visual Studio 19

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2019, localdb

I am pretty new to C# and VS and following the Pluralsight C# Generics course.
I have the LocalDB instance created and connected in SQL Server Object Explorer in VS and using Entity Framework for dealing with the data. There are no errors but the data is not entering the database. (In fact there is no database file created in my project directory). There is no output when I print the result of employeeRepo.FindAll().Count()

The relevant code is:

```
public class EmployeeDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    DbContext _ctx;
    DbSet<T> _set;
    public SqlRepository(DbContext ctx)
    {
         _ctx = ctx;
         _set = _ctx.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T newEntity)
    {
         _set.Add(newEntity);
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return _set;
    }
}
```

The Main and other functions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EmployeeDb>());

    using (IRepository<Employee> employeeRepo = new SqlRepository<Employee>(new EmployeeDb()))
    {
                
        AddEmployees(employeeRepo);
        CountEmployees(employeeRepo);
    }
}

private static void CountEmployees(IRepository<Employee> employeeRepo)
{
   Console.WriteLine(employeeRepo.FindAll().Count());
}

   private static void AddEmployees(IRepository<Employee> employeeRepo)
{
   employeeRepo.Add(new Employee { Name = "AA" });
   employeeRepo.Add(new Employee { Name = "BB" });
   employeeRepo.Commit();
}
```

Count() is present in System.Linq namespace. Expected output on the console is 2.
Any help/guidance is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this `set = _ctx.Set<T>();` correct? Should this be `_set = _ctx.Set<T>();`? Also I don't see you are calling the `Add` and `Commit` methods, where is that logic?

Comment: The code you posted can not be  even compilled. Pls post the whole real code including  AddEmployees(employeeRepo);   CountEmployees(employeeRepo);

Comment: Do you have `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty Sorry I used _set, did a typo here when posting the question.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry but where do I see that?

Comment: you said LocalDB instance created and connected to that in VS, Did you see if the records are available in the Employee table of that DB? As per your code there is no issue. Also where did this `FindAll()` come from?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty No there is no table created. Can you once please tell me the correct steps of connecting a LocalDB instance with a VS project. Maybe that's where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @SatashreeRoy, see this if it can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Comment: The connectionstring is normally In your project Settings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my project was not connecting to the SQL server and creating any database table. My bad, but learnt how to do it properly now.

Great video for those starting out with SQL server and Entity Framework
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=defBg85T8AU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX7_12fwQLU&list=RDCMUCWv7vMbMWH4-V0ZXdmDpPBA&start_radio=1&rv=ZX7_12fwQLU

Also, in my VS 19 .NET desktop development the App.config file is not created automatically. No problem, just create it from Add New Item. (Not sure what all needs to be added but for now just the connectionString item works.)

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.